# Visual Studio Code, медленно работает табуляция

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, редактор-текста

При вводе созданного сниппета и нажатия табуляции моментально, он не срабатывает, а для того, чтобы сработал, нужно подождать от полсекунды до секунды чтобы вылезла подсказка о моём сниппете и я смог нажать табуляцию.
Я привык работать быстро и меня это не совсем устраивает.

В Атоме, например, это всё работает моментально, но мне нравится VSCode.

Как мне осуществить быструю табуляция, либо же это всё VScode?

Comment: Оперативки добавить, удалить не используемые плагины, закрыть лишние терминалы и т.п

Comment: Оперативная память 8гб, используется 3гб при всех закрытых программах, отключил все плагины, терминалы и никаких изменений к сожалению.
Ладно, я уже отчаялся, эта проблема у меня уже достаточно давно, придётся переходить на другой редактор кода.
Но всё равно спасибо за отзывчивость!

Comment: У меня VSCode, в рабочем режиме более 1Гб оперативки - не потребляет

Comment: Я не про оперативную память VSCode, а про вообщем что система жрёт 3гб)
а так он жрёт около 100мб.
Но я вроде нашёл небольшой выход из этой ситуации, выключить Emmet. 
В настройках:
Emmet: show Expanded Abbreviation - never.
Emmet: Trigger Expansion on tab поставить галочку, и тогда будет практически счастье! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вроде нашёл небольшой выход из этой ситуации. В настройках VSCode:

**Emmet**: show Expanded Abbreviation - never.

**Emmet**: Trigger Expansion on tab поставить галочку.

И тогда будет практически счастье! :)

Comment: Спасибо! Практически счастье))